# Asymptotic expansion of the inverse of a matrix valued function

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics

A matrix valued function is of the form $\psi:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and it is known that $\psi(\lambda)$ is always a **positive definite** matrix. The asymptotic exapnsion of $\psi(\lambda)$ is given as $$\psi(\lambda) = A + \frac{B_1}{\lambda}+ \frac{B_2}{\lambda^2}+ \frac{B_3}{\lambda^3}+...$$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ **all ones** matrix and $B_1,B_2,B_3...$ are nonsingular $n\times n$ matrices.

I want to get an asymptotic expansion for $\psi(\lambda)^{-1}$. I don't want to compute the exact coefficient matrices but want to show that it is of the form $$\psi(\lambda)^{-1} = \lambda D_{-1} + D_0 + \frac{D_1}{\lambda} + \frac{D_2}{\lambda^2} + \frac{D_3}{\lambda^3} +...$$ where $D_{-1},D_0,D_1,D_2,..$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $D_{-1}$ is a non zero matrix.

What I know

[Neumann's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) and this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1268242/2987).

PS : if this isn't a research level problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we disregard the positivity constraint, this is not true in general, the leading order term can be of order $n-1$ rather than of order 1.

The problem is treated in [Laurent expansion of the inverse of perturbed, singular matrices](https://e-archivo.uc3m.es/bitstream/handle/10016/23560/laurent_JCP_2015_ps.pdf). The leading order term is of the order of the singularity in $A$, which for $A$ an $n\times n$ all-1 matrix is of order $n-1$.

Here is an example for $n=3$:
$$\psi=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1+\frac{1}{\lambda} & 1+\frac{4}{\lambda} \\
 1+\frac{1}{\lambda} & 1 & 1+\frac{1}{\lambda} \\
 1+\frac{4}{\lambda} & 1+\frac{1}{\lambda}& 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
has inverse of order $\lambda^2$:
$$\psi^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{8} {\lambda} (2 {\lambda}+1) & \frac{1}{2} {\lambda} ({\lambda}+1) & -\frac{1}{8} {\lambda} (2 {\lambda}-1) \\
 \frac{1}{2} {\lambda} ({\lambda}+1) & -{\lambda} ({\lambda}+2) & \frac{1}{2} {\lambda} ({\lambda}+1) \\
 -\frac{1}{8} {\lambda} (2 {\lambda}-1) & \frac{1}{2} {\lambda} ({\lambda}+1) & -\frac{1}{8} {\lambda} (2 {\lambda}+1) \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

I do not know how/if the positivity constraint modifies the order.

Comment: I notice I did not use your additional condition that $\psi$ is positive definite for all $\lambda$.

Comment: Yes, that's something need to be resolved. To see if it can make the leading $n-2$ matrices zero.

Comment: Oh the paper clearly says $H_{-s}$ is not zero. So thats about it?

Comment: I am confused by that statement; it does not hold, for example, for the matrix $A+I/\lambda$ for $n=3$, then the leading order term is of order $\lambda$, not $\lambda^2$.

Comment: In some of my computations too I observed the same. I get $\lambda$ increase and not any higher powers.

Comment: Also clearly the statement in that paper that $H_{-s} \ne 0$ is wrong as per your example $A+I/{\lambda}$ when $n = 3$.

Comment: The crucial for the answer is the value $s$ and it is not the order of singularity of $A$. It depends on first $p$ matrices in the series and there is a procedure to determine $s$. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/106b/31e8a3020c9c9820c3fb8da0e3269b88fc70.pdf?_ga=2.206622291.1745264539.1596903256-1361304415.1586702362